# How to expand ggplot axis by a given percentage for all facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to create a facet plot with ggplot and would like the expand the axes by a given percentage on each facet so I can annotate notes of the extra white spaces.  As an example, what's the best approach sat 25% more white space above the maximum value (or minimum value) in the following mock-up example? Please note in the code in which I'm attempting to achieve this I have about 50+ facets so I don't really want to set each scale extent individually.

```
require(tidyerse)

df <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = factor(Species))

ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~ Species, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand the scale using the `expand` argument of `scale_x/y_continuous` and the `expansion()` helper function, i.e. in the code I use `expansion(mult = c(.05, 1))` to keep the default expansion of 5 percent at the lower end and set the expansion at the upper end to 100 percent.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- iris %>%
  mutate(Species = factor(Species))

ggplot(data = iris, aes(
  x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width,
  colour = Species
)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(
    expand = expansion(mult = c(.05, 1))
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~Species, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]